# Cucumber Testing Rails Application on a Webrick Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, jrubyonrails

How to cucumber testing create in rails application which running on webrick server?

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber is pretty easy to work with. I would highly suggest that you watch these 2 railscasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber

http://railscasts.com/episodes/159-more-on-cucumber

If you already know a bit about regular expressions as well, cucumber will be a breeze to work with.